# How do I sort 2 arrays by timestamp using usort()

Tags: php, sorting, usort

I need to sort between 2 arrays by timestamp using `usort()`. The source below will show you what I have, and what I need to incorporate into the source I have to sort 2 arrays by timestamp with `usort()`.

Ignore the `db_open`,`db_query`,`db_fetch_all` functions in my php. These are functions I set up as short cuts.

**Here is what I've built to get my information, and merge the 2 arrays.**

```
$db = db_open();

$query = "
SELECT postings.posting_id, postings.timestamp AS posting_timestamp, users.user_name, groups.group_name FROM groups 
LEFT JOIN postings 
ON postings.group_id = groups.group_id 
LEFT JOIN users 
ON postings.user_id = users.user_id 
WHERE groups.user_id = '".$_SESSION['user']['user_id']."' 
AND postings.user_id != '".$_SESSION['user']['user_id']."'";

$result = db_query($db, $query);
$result1 = db_fetch_all($result);

$query = "SELECT postings.posting_headline, comments.timestamp AS comment_timestamp, users.user_name 
FROM postings 
LEFT JOIN comments 
ON comments.posting_id = postings.posting_id 
LEFT JOIN users 
ON comments.user_id = users.user_id WHERE postings.user_id = '".$_SESSION['user']['user_id']."' 
AND comments.user_id != '".$_SESSION['user']['user_id']."'";

$result = db_query($db, $query);
$result2 = db_fetch_all($result);

$result = array_merge((array)$result1, (array)$result2);
```

**Here is what I need to incorporate in my source above to sort through the arrays by timestamp. Question is, how do I do that?**
Also, I'm not really sure what `$a` and `$b` are. Can someone explain what they are pulling from my querys?

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

$a = array(3, 2, 5, 6, 1);

usort($a, "cmp");

foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: $value\n";
}
```

For more on usort: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: I'm not sure how to hook up it up to, at all, no example. I thought I made that clear.

Answer (score 0):

This one is using usort()

```
   function cmp($a, $b)
    {
        if ($a[2] == $b[2]) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($a[2] < $b[2]) ? -1 : 1;
    }
```

Another way is to use array_multisort:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $node) {
   $timestamps[$key]    = $node[2];
}
array_multisort($timestamps, SORT_ASC, $array);
```

Comment: You know I tried multi_sort, but it wasn't working well. I'll try yours. Also, what's the difference of using multi_sort over usort?

Comment: Can you provide an example using my query's above. I'm not sure what `$a` and `$b` are pulling from my query at this moment.

Comment: array_multisort is used to compare elements from different arrays (or sub-arrays) at the same time. If you want to compare elements of only one array, you can use usort. The fact that those elements are themselves arrays is irrelevant.

Comment: $a = array(1 => 'one', 2 => 'two', 3 => 'three'); The unset() function allows removing keys from an array.

Comment: $b = array_values($a);
// Now $b is array(0 => 'one', 1 =>'three')
Do you understand that ?

Comment: So to get a full understanding of it, here's an example: 

`<?php
// This:
$a = array( 'color' => 'red',
            'taste' => 'sweet',
            'shape' => 'round',
            'name'  => 'apple',
            4        // key will be 0
          );

$b = array('a', 'b', 'c');

// . . .is completely equivalent with this:
$a = array();
$a['color'] = 'red';
$a['taste'] = 'sweet';
$a['shape'] = 'round';
$a['name']  = 'apple';
$a[]        = 4;        // key will be 0

$b = array();
$b[] = 'a';
$b[] = 'b';
$b[] = 'c';`

?>  (Read down for explanation on this example)

Comment: I need to see how your example will pull back my arrays in order of timestamp. Please update your question with this please. Would be the easiest way to see how it's working with my example.